# Filter mysql query result with results from another table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, tablefilter

I need help with adding a filter to my already working sql query. I need to filter the result based on results in another table. Without adding the filter the code works fine, but once it's added I get the following error "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\buff\marketplace.php on line 10".

Here's my query code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, uid, jobId, serviceName, budget, description, start_date, end_date, date_created, priority, lat, lng, distance
                FROM (
                SELECT z.id,
                      z.uid,
                      z.jobId,
                      z.serviceName,
                      z.budget,
                      z.description,
                      z.start_date,
                      z.end_date,
                      z.date_created,
                      z.priority,
                      z.lat, z.lng,
                      p.radius,
                      p.distance_unit
                               * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                               * COS(RADIANS(z.lat))
                               * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.lng))
                               + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                               * SIN(RADIANS(z.lat)))) AS distance
                FROM marketplace AS z
                JOIN (   /* these are the query parameters */
                      SELECT  $lat  AS latpoint,  $lng AS longpoint,
                              50.0 AS radius,      111.045 AS distance_unit
                  ) AS p

                WHERE marketplace.sid IN (SELECT sid FROM selectedservice WHERE uid=$uid AND is_approve=1) AND status=1 AND uid != $uid AND z.lat
                   BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
                       AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
                  AND z.lng
                   BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
                       AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
                ) AS d
                WHERE distance <= radius
                ORDER BY distance
                LIMIT 15";
```

Here is the line I added to filter the result:

```
marketplace.sid IN (SELECT sid FROM selectedservice WHERE uid=$uid AND is_approve=1)
```

And here is the rest of the code that's currently working without the filter.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, uid, jobId, serviceName, budget, description, start_date, end_date, date_created, priority, lat, lng, distance
                FROM (
                SELECT z.id,
                      z.uid,
                      z.jobId,
                      z.serviceName,
                      z.budget,
                      z.description,
                      z.start_date,
                      z.end_date,
                      z.date_created,
                      z.priority,
                      z.lat, z.lng,
                      p.radius,
                      p.distance_unit
                               * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                               * COS(RADIANS(z.lat))
                               * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.lng))
                               + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                               * SIN(RADIANS(z.lat)))) AS distance
                FROM marketplace AS z
                JOIN (   /* these are the query parameters */
                      SELECT  $lat  AS latpoint,  $lng AS longpoint,
                              50.0 AS radius,      111.045 AS distance_unit
                  ) AS p

                WHERE status=1 AND uid != $uid AND z.lat
                   BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
                       AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
                  AND z.lng
                   BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
                       AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
                ) AS d
                WHERE distance <= radius
                ORDER BY distance
                LIMIT 15";
```

selectedservice  and marketplace are tables both having sid and uid fields. $uid is the logged in user's id that's available throughout the page.

I just need to know how to squeeze in the above filter to display results the user is enabled for rather than all results.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you need to alter SQL code, do not post PHP code, please...

Comment: If you follow the suggestions in the duplicate and still have problems, create a new question with the SQL and the full error message and perhaps the table definition so that enough information is available to properly answer the question.

Comment: Hi Nigel, I don't see how "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?" is related to my question. I simply need guideline on how to add a query to my code. I think my question explains what I need. The above link is totally different from what I'm asking for.